# User script at logout

Tags: scripts, logout

**The problem**: I'm sharing a directory with my wife. I've placed us both in a 'shared' group and the directory belongs to the 'shared' group as well. Whenever one of us creates a file, this file belongs to user:user, instead of user:shared...

**The solution**: I can do sudo chown, but my wife can't. So, I want to run a script when I logout of the session.

If I understand correctly, the startup scripts go in /etc/init.d/ and the runlevel scripts go /etc/rc0.d/ where 0 is the runlevel (0-6).

**Questions:**
Do the runlevel scripts execute only on exit/logout? Do these depend on the user, that is, I'd like to run it only for my user (not so important in this case, mind)? Which runlevel should I choose (my guess is 5)? Should I place the script somewhere else?

Also, I imagine that the script will be run by root, so there's no need for sudo within the script, is that correct?

Comment: Not strictly duplicate, but future users may be interested in my solution to [How can I run a local command (to run a script) on (just before) log out of a Unity session?](http://askubuntu.com/q/720380/295286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use setgid bit?

From `man 2 chmod`:

> S_ISGID  (02000)  set-group-ID  (set  process  effective  group  ID 
>   on  execve(2);  mandatory locking, as described in fcntl(2); take a
>   new file's group from parent directory, as described in chown(2) and
>   mkdir(2))

Runlevel scripts are executed only on runlevel changes.

See also this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/65460/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-linux

Comment: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories). This is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Tested and it works. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

- Do the runlevel scripts execute only on exit/logout?

Those in /etc/init.d only on startup/shutdown, not while switching user/logout/login.

- Do these depend on the user, that is, I'd like to run it only for my user (not so important in this case, mind)?

Since they run before login: No, they don't depend on the user.

- Which runlevel should I choose (my guess is 5)?

Ubuntu uses normally 2 as standard runlevel. You can test it with

```
runlevel
```

in the shell.

- Should I place the script somewhere else?
  according to brownian, you could use ~/.logout, but a better solution is, to produce the files with a proper Group-ID. This can be done with starting the editor with sg.

  **sg share gedit**

`sg` acts similar to `su` - switch user/switch group. Maybe you can put a starter into your panels, for easy access. Brownians solution for the whole directory looks even better.

- Also, I imagine that the script will be run by root, so there's no need for sudo within the script, is that correct?

That's correct.

Comment: runlevel returns 2. I was thinking of reforming this question so that Brownian's answer makes sense and creating another question for the logout script, as there is no easy gooooogle answer available.