# How can I run a local command (to run a script) on (just before) log out of a Unity session?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, scripts, lightdm, logout

At the risk of posting a duplicate question:

*How can I run a local script (as the current user) when I log out?*

#### I read (and tried) among others:

1. [This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624374/how-to-run-a-script-at-logout) (Marton's version), which did perfectly nothing, used on a simple script creating a file, absolute paths to the script (being executable) and the file.
2. [This one](https://askubuntu.com/a/323767/72216), which must be outdated; it made me remove the file from command line to be able to use my system again.
3. I also looked into [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517633/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-unity-login-logout), without succes.

I believe I must be doing something wrong here, but cannot find out what is my blind spot.

#### Context

Looking for an elegant solution (workaround) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720193/unity-icon-positions-forgotten-on-boot-on-dual-monitor-setup), presumably the result of a bug, I made a script that, depending on the argument, either *takes a snapshot* of the current desktop icon arrangement, or *arranges the icons*, according to the last snapshot. The script works fine, but is really no candidate to run as a background script.

The script therefore should run on logout to *get* the arrangement, obviously run by the current user.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you targeting? From 15.04 I would expect you'd need to hook into `systemd` rather than `upstart`. Sorry that I can't be more specific but I haven't looked at the user facilities of systemd in detail.

Comment: @zwets Ah, I should have mentioned,: 14.04 (lightdm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Basic theory

As you may or may not know , a lot of Unity actions are implemented using [dbus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) . The big convenience about dbus is that you can perform lots of root-required actions by calling appropriate methods in command-line without need of having admin account, for instance [shutting down your system](https://askubuntu.com/a/1367/295286).

Specifically in our case here we are interested in `com.canonical.Unity` service, `/com/canonical/Unity/Session` path. You can list information about it with `qdbus` command. Particularly we're interested in signals that have `Requested` in them.

```
$ qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session | grep 'signal.*Requested.*'                             
signal void com.canonical.Unity.Session.LockRequested()
signal void com.canonical.Unity.Session.LogoutRequested(bool have_inhibitors)
signal void com.canonical.Unity.Session.RebootRequested(bool have_inhibitors)
signal void com.canonical.Unity.Session.ShutdownRequested(bool have_inhibitors)
signal void com.canonical.Unity.Session.UnlockRequested()
```

These signals appear on the bus when user clicks any of the shutdown, lock, logout, or reboot items in the drop-down session menu on the right side of the Unity's top bar. So what we need to do is this:

- monitor the bus for those signals to appear.
- once they appear - perform a certain action.

Of course , the *big disclamer* is that if a user uses `sudo shutdown -P now` or `gnome-session-quit` , that won't be told to the `dbus` , so whatever action is wanted won't be done.

### Monitoring the dbus

Conveniently there is a command for that, `dbus-monitor` and we can filter its output using a set of options, and perform an action on it using `while read do … done` structure

Bellow is an example of  a simple monitoring script.

```sh
dbus-monitor --profile "interface='com.canonical.Unity.Session',type=signal" | \
while read -r line;
do
  echo "$line" 
  sleep 0.25
done
```

What it does is merely monitor the bus for signals , and echo them back to stdout if they appear; of course echo could be any command. Run it , and try clicking on each item in the session menu that should generate signals, and you should see something like this:

```
$ ./logout_monitor.sh                                                                                             
sig 1458319246  172587  2   /org/freedesktop/DBus   org.freedesktop.DBus    NameAcquired
sig 1458319251  213766  5496    /com/canonical/Unity/Session    com.canonical.Unity.Session RebootRequested
sig 1458319265  62555   5525    /com/canonical/Unity/Session    com.canonical.Unity.Session LogoutRequested
sig 1458319271  856770  5555    /com/canonical/Unity/Session    com.canonical.Unity.Session LockRequested
sig 1458319273  223940  5564    /com/canonical/Unity/Session    com.canonical.Unity.Session Locked
sig 1458319276  991413  5604    /com/canonical/Unity/Session    com.canonical.Unity.Session UnlockRequested
sig 1458319278  3443    5606    /com/canonical/Unity/Session    com.canonical.Unity.Session Unlocked
```

So now we have a monitoring function that can perform an action once an interrupt occurs. Now , to address the specific question that you were trying to solve , your script is taking snapshots of the icons on the desktop. There's no harm done if we take snapshot each time a signal occurs - it doesn't have to be reboot or shutdown specifically. So if we monitor that specific Unity interface for signals and take snapshots upon each signal's arrival, we can simplify the scripting.

**Interrupt-driven script**

Bellow you can see an interrupt-driven script which will monitor the bus for signals (ignoring the first one ) and if we have a signal coming in , then call an interrupt function (which in your case will be the icon snapshot script that you've written).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

main()
{
  ARG="cow"
  dbus-monitor --profile "interface='com.canonical.Unity.Session',type=signal" | 
  while read -r line;
  do
    grep -q '.*NameAcquired.*' <<< "$line"  && continue  #  Ignore that first line
    if [ -n "$line"  ];then
       interrupt $ARG # call your python snapshot script here
    fi
  done
}

interrupt()
{
  echo 'Old McDonald had a ' $ARG ' e-i-e-i-o '
}

main
```

**NOTE**: Dbus relies on having GUI session , since (as far as I know) it starts with Unity/Gnome login. Older environments such as blackbox and openbox, as well as TTY environments *do not* start dbus session, hence that script will puke if you try to launch it in `~/.profile` (I had one user who tried to do something like that and he got into trouble). *Start such script using Unity's or Gnome's Startup Applications* program.

### Going beyond this script

- Dbus has a lot of API's including [python](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/)
- I prefer using `qdbus` because it's simple, but one could always use `dbus-send` . [Examples](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190/how-can-i-make-shutdown-not-require-admin-password)
- The interrupt function can be anything, even other `dbus` methods. There's a lot to look into.

*Trivia*: I've used this same method for [preventing shutdown if apt is running](https://askubuntu.com/a/713590/295286)

Comment: This looks very promising, will look later today!

Comment: `main() … main` O.o What have you been smoking recently?

Comment: @muru mostly Pall Mall  . . .What ? It's no different than having `def main:` in python and then calling `if __ name __ == "__ main __": main` . Besides , I kind of miss C style formatting in  bash scripts. Doesnt' that look pretty ?

Comment: No, it looks ugly. In Python, it might have some purpose, I really don't see the sense in shell scripts. And I'm sure it's illegal to call `main` in C.

Comment: You already had me with the monitoring script. This is the roadd I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of `dbus`, which is mostly an unexplored area to me.